# powershell set database settings

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to build an XML-File containing various settings of a database in order to read this file and set the database Settings using PowerShell.
Say the XML-file Looks like that:

```
<database Name="db1">
        <serviceBroker>True</serviceBroker>
        <dbcollation>Latin...</Collation>
        <dbRecoveryModel>Full</dbRecoveryModel>
</database>"
```

there is no one-fits-all method to set the properties, collation is a string, ServiceBroker is a boolean etc...
how to solve this Problem?
thanks for any help
Purclot

Comment: Are you asking how to change the settings of an existing database to match those in the XML using PowerShell? That can be done in PS using T-SQL or SMO. The data types expressed in the XML are not relevant in that case,

Comment: Who or what will be consuming that file?

Comment: Dan, I'll be exchanging the the XML-file with another team, they want the server/databases look like describe in this file. All the properties/Settings from above (serviceBroker, dbcollation) come from SMO-Class..

Comment: Ansgar, I've just posted an answer for Dan...I'll be consuming the file. The idea is to get the database/Server Settings in form of an XML from another team, Loop through the file with PowerShell and set/Change the Settings..

Comment: @Purclot, it would be best to specify in your question (rather than a comment) that your goal is to use SMO in PS to apply the settings specified in the XML. Add the code you've tried to your question too.